# Two UIPickerViews on same iOS view, but values show up as question marks

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I'm making a single view iOS application. I have two UIPickerView elements and initialize them in a for loop creating a bunch of strings for each. I hide one of them on viewDidLoad because I plan to toggle between them. The one that is displaying shows "?" for each row instead of the proper string.

viewcontroller.h is below

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet NSMutableArray *milesArray;
    IBOutlet NSMutableArray *metersArray;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *distanceText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *distanceUnits;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *timeText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *splitLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *meterText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *feetText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *inchesText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *meterPicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *milePicker;

- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;

@end
```

viewcontroller.m is next

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <math.h>

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    milesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    metersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    _meterText.text = @"0";
    _feetText.text = @"0";
    _inchesText.text = @"0";
    _distanceText.text = @"0";
    _timeText.text = @"00:00:00.00";

    _milePicker.hidden = YES;
    //set picker data
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (i+1)*100];

        [metersArray addObject:str];

        NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f", (i+1)*0.1];

        [milesArray addObject:str1];
    }

    self.meterPicker.dataSource = self;
    self.milePicker.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender{
    [self.view endEditing:(YES)];
}


// The number of columns of data
- (long)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

// The number of rows of data
- (long)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(pickerView.tag == 6)
    {
        return metersArray.count;
    }
    else if(pickerView.tag == 7)
    {
        return milesArray.count;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(pickerView.tag == 6)
    {
        return metersArray[row];
    }
    else if(pickerView.tag == 7)
    {
        return milesArray[row];
    }

    else
        return @"error";
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    long index = row;

    _splitLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", index];
}
@end
```

I think it has something to do with initializing them when you have two instead of just one uipickerview. I'm probably doing something wrong with that.

Thanks in advance, I hope everything is fairly clear.

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors in your code:

1. In your .h, you are initializating the NSArras with IBOutlet. Why? They should be just `NSMutableArray xxxxArray`
2. Not that bad, in the .h, the pickers should be both weak properties.

I hope the 1st error fix your problem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: None of this addresses the issue of seeing question marks in the picker view.

Answer (score 0):

One big issue are the following two lines in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.meterPicker.dataSource = self;
self.milePicker.delegate = self;
```

You don't set the `dataSource` for the mile picker and you don't set the `delegate` for the meter picker.

You want:

```
self.meterPicker.dataSource = self;
self.meterPicker.delegate = self;
self.milePicker.dataSource = self;
self.milePicker.delegate = self;
```

Better yet, use just one picker view. When you wish to change between miles and meters, simply reload the one picker view and setup your two delegate methods to use the proper array based on the current mode.